# What does it mean that BIP141 is "buried" in Bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, segregated-witness, soft-fork, bip90-buried-deployments

I am reading the list of BIPs implemented in Bitcoin core ([link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/bips.md)) and it says that BIP141 is "buried since v0.19.0", what does that mean? Does this mean that what written in BIP141 is no longer relevant in Bitcoin Core or does it have some completely different meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a buried softfork deployment was introduced in [BIP 90](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0090.mediawiki).

In short, it means that the softfork's consensus rules are generally active *on every block* (possibly with a few known exceptions), rather than following the activation mechanism that was used historically for the softfork. The BIP goes into rationale and considerations.